# Limit the RFID band

Tags: rfid, motorola

I am working with RFID, using Motorola FX7400 reader to read tags, all that without much trouble. 
This reader operates in a determined frequency(902 MHz to 928 MHz).
I want to limit this frequency to two bands, one going from 902 to 907 and another going from 915 to 928. I searched the API for something like that but I couldn't find anything. Is that possible? Has anyone tried that? Someone? Please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone with the same problem: The solution I arrived is that I need to put a firmware who meets that criteria.
I've got this answer in a RFID training, with people who has expertise with this tecnology.

This answer is applicable only for Motorola FX Series. For other brands and series, consult your vendor.